# In IntelliJ debug mode, is it possible to pause an execution whenever a certain condition is met?

Tags: intellij-idea

This feature is particularly going to be useful inside a huge loop. Consider, I would want to see the current state of the system, when I reach a particular iteration of a loop. If, there's a way to let IntelliJ continue the execution till a particular condition is met, I would save lot of time without having the need to iterate through each iteration manually.

Example:
    for(int i = 0;i < 7000; i++){
    ...
    }

In the above example, I would want to pause the execution when the value of i becomes say "121". Ideally, I would have to either change my code to wrap inside an if condition to check for the value "121" or iterate through the values from 0-121.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible toset a condition to breakpoint.
See this: https://www.baeldung.com/intellij-debugging-tricks#conditional-breakpoints

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you @Alexander Terekhov!